# Writing CSV directly to a BYTEA column from PostgreSQL tables

Tags: postgresql, csv, cast, bytea

Assuming these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE data (day DATE, kpi INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE reports (csv BYTEA);
```

Is it possible to (pseudocode):

```
INSERT INTO reports (csv) (SELECT to_csv(SELECT day, kpi FROM data));
```

with the result being a CSV stored as BYTEA in table reports, column csv?

I specifically do not want to go through the filesystem (COPY, etc.).

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738331

Comment: Thanks! Is it best to migrate the original question or delete it? I think this community is a better fit.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  Is it just storing your CSVs?  If so, wouldn't it be better to store them on the filesystem?

Comment: The CSV data has to be stored back to the database where it will be picked up by a web application, and the web application cannot be modified to produce the CSV itself. The database user does not have access to the filesystem, but it can define functions and triggers.

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you need to write the `to_csv` function, and first, decide what are going to be its argument(s).